# For which $a$ and $b$ is this matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For which $a$ and $b$ is this matrix diagonalizable?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & b \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ b & 0 & a  \end{pmatrix}$$

How to get those $a$ and $b$? I calculated eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but don't know what to do next?

Answer (score 8):

That is a symmetric matrix: it is **always** diagonalizable over a field with characteristic$\;\neq2\;$. Not only that: it is *orthogonally* diagonalizable.

Comment: What if $a,b \in \mathbb C$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo then the result is still a normal matrix

Comment: No, it's not always diagonalisable. It's diagonalisable if and only if $b=0$ or the field has characteristic $\ne2$. For a counterexample, consider $a=0$ and $b=1$ over $GF(2)$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you, though I think this is a very particular case, specially because this kind of questions are many times related to inner product spaces, which are usually the reals or the complex ones. Yet I will edit to cover even this case.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the eigenvalues, $b, b+a, a-b,$ one can then easily calculate their respective eigenvectors.  For eigenvalue $b,$
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} a-b&0&b\\0&0&0\\b&0&a-b \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
There may be special cases, such as if $a = 0,$ then the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ works too.

Likewise for $a+b,$
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} -b&0&b\\0&-a&0\\b&0&-b \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

And last for $a-b,$
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} b&0&b\\0&2b-a&0\\b&0&b \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Because no assumptions about the values of $a$ and $b$ were made along the way, this operator must be diagonalizable (which we already knew from symmetry), with an eigenbasis \begin{equation} \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}, 
\text{ and } 
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}

---

Note that if one remembers that matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ b& a \end{pmatrix} $ have the eigenbasis $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1& -1 \end{pmatrix},$
then from a quick glance at the original matrix, you can already "know" the eigenvectors since this $2 \times 2$ is hidden within it.

Answer (score -1):

Matrix A has 3 eigenvalues a-b, a+b and b. In order for them to be distinguishable, following conditions should be met. $$b \ne 0$$ $$a \ne 0$$ $$a \ne 2b$$

Comment: Why the third one? How to get that?

Comment: $a-b \ne b$ leads to $a \ne 2b$

Comment: Okay. But from what you get that? I dont understand.

Comment: you first calculate eigenvalues $det( \lambda I-A)=0$.

Comment: Okay, I understand that part b,a-b and a+b. but why a-b=b (why this "b" at the right)?

Comment: What do "distinguishable eigenvalues" mean? Perhaps that they are *different*? Anyway, what do we need this for?

Comment: yes, all eigenvalues should be different, otherwise the matrix cannot be converted to a diagonal.

Comment: Of course this is not true. For example, the identity matrix has all of its eigenvalues equal, yet it is diagonalizable (it is already diagonal). What matters is that for each eigenvalue, the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are equal.

Comment: OK, if they are different, the matrix is diagonalizable though this is not a necessity condition.